# Where to store a variable when needed in the next run?

Tags: c, variables, scope

I'm changing a program written in C. 
For these changes I need a counter (variable int). When the run stops, I need the value of this counter in the following run of the program. (even if the pc is restarted in between).
What is the best way to store this value? I was thinking about the following : storing it as a registry-value, writing it to a file (not preferred, somebody might delete this file), using persistent variables (but I can't find many information on these).
Or, are there other ways to keep this variable?
The program has to run in a Windows environment and in a Linux environment (as it does now).

Comment: The only way to persist data across runs is files (or some other data store, but for a simple counter, a file is the easiest).

Comment: Well no registry on linux ... what's wrong with a file? You can detect its absence.

Comment: AND where is the program?

Comment: What's a "persistent variable"? And why would a file be any more likely to be deleted than a registry entry (which would only be of use on Windows, anyway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in a file. If you want to protect the file from accidental deletion, have its name start with a period on Linux (`.myfile`) or mark it as "hidden" on Windows. If you want to protect it against more than just accidental deletion, the registry is no better than a file.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I think would be to store it in a database.  Have you got any database experience?  Could you store it in MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I have access to databases, but this product has to be installed with different clients. I can't oblige them to set up a database for just 1 counter.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have a concept of "persistent variables"; no actual programming language that I know of has that.

A file would be the best choice; detecting its absense and protesting/failing will be trivial.